# Initial offset of consumer group with none auto.offset.reset.policy

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, message-listener

I have auto.offset.reset=none in my consumer because I need to know about OutOfRangeException event.

I have MessageListenereContainer with custom ErrorHandler where I catch OutOfRange exception and manually do seekToEnd for my consumer.

That's great and absolutelly what I need.

But if it's new consumer group that's problem.
Kafka considers it's fatal error and stop my consumer with NoOffsetForPartitionException because for new consumer group offset is undefined (1239 row of KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java).
What is the right way do not use auto.offset.reset but be able manually set initial offset for new consumer group?

I use MessageListenerContainer for consuming.

Comment: Why not use `auto.offset.reset=latest` if you're going to seek there anyway? That's your only other option for the behavior you want

Comment: Because I need to handle OutOfRangeException. It's the first sentence:) Between catch and seek I have some handling logic important for us. With auto.offset.reset  latest or earliest kafka does it for me. But I need to check this event.

Comment: Are you not able to catch `NoOffsetForPartitionException` with the error handler?

Comment: Yes, I can't, because this exception is handled in KafkaMessageListenerContainer class, 1239 row. It's marked as fatal and is not thrown further. This behavior is typical only for a new consumer group.

Comment: Sounds like you should file this an an issue with the Spring-Kafka project. Have you tried doing the same with plain `KafkaConsumer` API? No annotations or Spring properties?